# Catch 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte X in position X: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

I was trying to open a file in the following way:

```
file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
```

But all I got was the following error message:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 75: invalid start byte
```

So I thought, let's catch the error and let's fallback to `errors=ignore` in the following way:

```
try:
    file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
except UnicodeError as decode_error:
    file = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
```

But nothing, I always get the same error message, it seems I can't catch the error. I also tried with `OSError, IOError, UnicodeDecodeError, RuntimeError, Exception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the file does not read it.

Therefore, `open` will never throw a `UnicodeDecodeError`. Attempting to read the file will.

Open will throw when the file is not there (`FileNotFoundError`) or when you don't have sufficient permissions (`PermissionError`).

You must catch the `UnicodeDecodeError` in another place in your application.

That being said, if you are prepared to ignore Unicode decode errors anyway then there is no reason to open the file with `errors='strict'` in the first place.